# How to play .m3u8 file streaming url with AudioStreamer?

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, audiostreamer

I have an iOS streaming app, that is integrated with `AudioStreamer`. It works fine for my streaming urls. But suddenly thay have change the streaming url into .m3u8 format. How can I use `AudioStreamer` for .m3u8 file url?

I cant use `MPMoviePlayer` because I want to show some buffering before load the stream. It can easily done with the `AudioStreamer`. How can I use `AudioStreamer` to play an .m3u8 file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and parse the m3u8 file and get the actual URL to the resource and then pass that URL to AudioStreamer.

[Here](https://github.com/Jeanvf/M3U8Paser) you can find M3U8Parser lib that parse the playlist.

Below is an example of m3u8 format:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10

#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1

#EXTINF:10,
http://video.example.com/segment0.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://video.example.com/segment1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://video.example.com/segment2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```